# How to convert latitude longitude to azimuth coordinates for d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a list of latitude and longitude points and I want to create an azimuth projection like this one: http://boydgreenfield.com/quakes/

I'm confused on how to get the 3 coordinate input into the azimuth projection from the latitude and longitude. I'm simply looking for how to convert between the two.

Here's a related question I found, but hasn't helped me:

[Animating D3 globe (d3.geo.azimuthal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769083/d3-javascript-library-d3-geo-azimuthal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear how it is that you have a 3-coordinate input. Isn't it a 2-coordinate input (i.e. lat/lng)? I'll assume that's what you mean :-/

So, if you have a longitude and latitude of, say, NYC:

`var nycLngLat = [74.0, 40.7];`

and you have some projection, e.g:

`var projection = d3.geo.azimuthalEqualArea();`

then you can find out the projected X and Y simply by "calling" the projection instance (since it's also a function):

`var nycXY = projection(nycLngLat);`

One thing to note is that d3 defined geo coordinates as Longitude, Latitude. It's the opposite of the Google Maps way –– in case you were used to that.

Comment: Awesome, for some reason when I was debugging the example I had put up I thought they were passing in 3 points and that made no sense to me. Thanks for clearing it up!